# Nested templates using ui-view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display a nested template using `ui-view`.

AngularJS routing config

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '',
                abstract: true
            })
            .state('home.default', {
                parent: 'home',
                url: '/home',
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Homepage'
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/default/default.html',
                        controller: 'defaultController',
                        controllerAs: 'defaultController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('default.subview', {
                parent: 'default',
                url: '/default/subview',
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Homepage - subview'
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/subview/subview.html',
                        controller: 'subviewController',
                        controllerAs: 'subviewController'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;
    }]);
```

Home: `/#/home`

```
<!-- this URI should be #/home -->
<h2>Homepage</h2>

<select>
    <option>Subview</option>
</select>

<hr>

<!-- nested subview -->
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Subview: `/#/home/subview`

```
<h2>Subview</h2>
```

So basically, I want the parent view (home) and subview's content to be included when I visit (/#/home/subview). However, only the subview content is being displayed.

Any tips on how to correctly utilize `ui-view` and nested subviews in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Your subview has to be a child of home and you set the subview  with 'content@' to an defined ui-view wich replaces your view from home.

And I edited some copy paste issue since it looks like your home route was called default before

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('home.default', {

        url: '/home/default',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Homepage'
        },
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'defaultController',
                controllerAs: 'defaultController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home.subview', {
        parent: 'home',
        url: '/subview',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Homepage - subview'
        },
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'subview.html',
                controller: 'subviewController',
                controllerAs: 'subviewController'
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

**Edit:**

I created a Plunker with an working configuration, there was some more issues with that abstract home state (I never get it to work as expected) but if you click the links everything appears as expected.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B5ryJ0PC5uDROaLkrAvl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There really is no need for the `views` section if you have only one `ui-view`

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
        })
        .state('home.default', {
            // parent: 'home', // No need to set parent if you already prefixed state name
            url: '', // The default subview of an abstract view should have '' for url
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Homepage'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/default/default.html',
            controller: 'defaultController',
            controllerAs: 'defaultController'
        })
        .state('home.default.subview', {
            // parent: 'default', // No ned for parent
            url: '/subview', // Only pu the part of the url here that is added to the parent'ls url
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Homepage - subview'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/subview/subview.html',
            controller: 'subviewController',
            controllerAs: 'subviewController'
        })
    ;
}]);
```

In addition I've also changed the ui-sref in `index.html`

```
<a ui-sref="home.default.subview">Subview Route</a>
```

And the ui-view in `home.html`

```
<!-- nested subview -->
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Check this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vEDYvXhp5mNjVT0yLRJN?p=preview